# Phone Number Formats as Keywords

Tags: seo, keywords

A pretty simple question: Phone Numbers can be written in many way from 123-456-7899 to (123) 456 7899 and 1234567899 is there point in putting multiple phone number formats in your website for the sake of having those keywords or are crawlers smart enough to compare phone number with different formats? Assuming we have a site like... YellowPages, let's say, that has lost of pages and phones on them, and user is looking up just the phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engines are pretty smart and can figure out what a phone number looks like as long as you use a common format.

But you can help them out by using [microformats](http://schema.org/telephone) and marking up the phone number which clearly tells the search engines that number is a phone number.

Comment: aahhh, very nice! I will use that for sure! Thanks!

Comment: I had done several quick searches on the net for any advice on formatting phone numbers. Short of database, JavaScrpt, API, libraries, and other situations where format must be explicit, I could not find any advice on formatting a phone number for the web. This seems odd to me. I would have thought someone would have at least given some advice somewhere over the vast number of years, but I did not find it. This is a strong clue that format does not matter. The only advice I found was to be consistent.